# Count rows in own type such as type as table or type as object

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-table, sql-types

My own type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE chain_t AS TABLE OF NUMBER(11);
```

select column as this type in select statement

```
select 
x.id, 
cast(multiset(select parent_id from table(x.parents)) as chain_t) as chain
from
xxxx x
```

if **x.parents** have values i have next result, for example:

```
chain_t(22, 44)
```

or if dont have

```
chain_t(null)
```

How i can count rows in **chain**?? 
For example in first result 2 rows in second result 0 rows

Comment: You could use another table function and count that? Why aren't you just counting the number of parents though? Why are you using multiset? What is `parents`? Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to achieve including sample data?

Comment: it is minimal example, really when i use multiset it is sub query in top query i want know count rows in chain

Comment: You count rows in the the type `chain_t` by `select count(*) from table(chain_t(<data>))`, but I don't understand why you don't just do `select count(*) from table(x.parents)`, which is why I'm asking you what your actual table and data looks like are and why you're using everything else. Your example may be minimal but it is not verifiable or complete. I can't run this as I don't know what everything is - I have to make it up. You could understand a request for more information as an indication that your question isn't 100% clear and you're therefore less likely to get a satisfactory answer..

Comment: i need count in my select statement, because this (in my question) select statement in not editable view which use type chain_t and don't return x.parents column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CARDINALITY()` function.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions022.htm#sthref961).

```
select id, chain, cardinality(chain) 
from (
   select 
           x.id, 
           cast(multiset(select parent_id from x) as chain_t) as chain
    from x
)
/
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle based on this simplified version of your posted code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47e616/1).

Comment: Thanks! really what i want!